# Fixing a UITextField and UIButton to the bottom x% of an iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITextField` (`input`), and a `UIButton` (`_saveButton`), that I want to sit on the bottom 20% of the screen, the `input` above the `_saveButton`.

It seems that the best way to do this is to make the `mainScreen` height the y bound, and have the `self.view` that contains these two elements to sit on a y coordinate of 0. I've tried this below, but they both sit at the top of the screen. What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Text Input
    input = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
    input.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    input.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    input.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times-New-Roman" size:25];
    input.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [input setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    input.placeholder=@"Type words here";

    //The View that holds input
    UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 400, 400)];
    [inputView addSubview:input];

    //Save Button
    _saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    _saveButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 18);
    [_saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //The View that holds saveButton
    UIView *saveButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    [saveButtonView addSubview:_saveButton];

    // Add input and saveButton to the main View
    [self.view addSubview:inputView];
    [self.view addSubview:saveButtonView];

    //Fix to bottom of screen
    float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height;
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Here's how I want it to look, but without having to use explicit numbers, since that will break with different screen sizes:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "on the bottom 20%"? Can you maybe provide a picture?

Comment: @JoshCaswell added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I hacked this up because I need to go make dinner for my kids, but I believe it does what you want. I erred on the size of creating many extra variables so that you could hopefully intuit what I'm doing where.

In short, you were improperly calculating the origins of `inputView` and `saveButtonView`.

I've calculated them here to begin 80% of the way down the view, as you requested in your original post. I set the Y origin of `inputView` to that 80% number. I calculate the X offsets necessary to center both the input field and the save button. I set the Y origin of `saveButtonView` to that 80% plus the height of `inputView` plus an arbitrary spacing constant.

If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask questions.

Also, out of curiosity, are you opposed to using Storyboards and constraints, instead of doing this all in code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITextField *input;

        CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        CGPoint screenOrigin = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin;
        CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        CGPoint screenCenter = CGPointMake(screenOrigin.x + (screenWidth / 2), screenOrigin.y + (screenHeight / 2));
        CGFloat topOfViews = screenHeight * 0.8; // Views begin 80% of way down view (AKA 20% from bottom)


        //Text Input
        input = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
        input.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        input.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        input.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times-New-Roman" size:25];
        input.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [input setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
        input.placeholder=@"Type words here";

        //The View that holds input
        CGFloat inputX = screenCenter.x - input.frame.size.width / 2;
        CGFloat inputY = topOfViews;
        CGRect inputFrame = CGRectMake(inputX, inputY, input.frame.size.width, input.frame.size.height);
        UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:inputFrame];
        [inputView addSubview:input];

        //Save Button
        _saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        _saveButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 18);
        [_saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //The View that holds saveButton
        const CGFloat ARBITRARY_VERTICAL_SPACE = 24;
        CGFloat saveX = screenCenter.x - _saveButton.frame.size.width / 2;
        CGFloat saveY = inputFrame.origin.y + inputFrame.size.height + ARBITRARY_VERTICAL_SPACE;
        CGRect saveFrame = CGRectMake(saveX, saveY, _saveButton.frame.size.width, _saveButton.frame.size.height);
        UIView *saveButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:saveFrame];
        [saveButtonView addSubview:_saveButton];

        // Add input and saveButton to the main View
        [self.view addSubview:inputView];
        [self.view addSubview:saveButtonView];

        //Fix to bottom of screen
        float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height;
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What I can think of a solution is to add a dummy view(for layout purpose and it should be transparent) that is proportional 20% of the whole screen. And your UI widgets can have a pin to that dummy view by using **Auto-Layout**.